# Unable the load right pdo driver in xampp 3.2.2

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp

I am using **Xampp v3.2.2** I need to add Pthe DO driver. I have downloaded

```
;extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
;extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
;extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
;extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
;extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension =php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
;extension =php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
;extension =php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
;extension =php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
;extension =php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
;extension =php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension =php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

and activated the **56_ts driver**. But still, this error is showing:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\location\config.php:8

I'm using **32 bits Windows 7**.  Which driver should I activate for running my program?

Comment: You need to also install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36434.

Comment: Your php is thread safe?

Comment: Microsoft ODBC Driver have alreary

Comment: Thread Safety enabled

Comment: Do you restart the apache? the process you did seems ok

Comment: yes i have done many times

Comment: Please contact me https://www.facebook.com/mittalsanjog

Comment: Do you put the .dll file at folder `ext`?

Comment: yeah i have done dis one

Comment: Check what version you need to use here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx